# Error sending message to DM of a user discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I am currently trying to send a message to a user's DM but I only get the following error

```
user = client.get_user(499642019191324692)
AttributeError: module 'discord.client' has no attribute 'get_user'
```

This is my code

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = client.get_user(499642019191324692)
    await user.send('Hello')
```

Comment: the user id must be string i guess... and also, a user don't have ```send``` attribute, you can just ping the user in your msg

Comment: @GhostOps Surely you must realize that would be an entirely different error.

Comment: You have done `from discord import client`, but you must create an object of type `Client`.  That's where the `get_user` method is located.

Comment: yeah, and also, why its showing ```discord.client``` ? shouldn't be like ```discord.Client``` ?

Comment: @TimRoberts I have the `from discord import client`
imported since before the error occurs I don't think that is it

Comment: @GhostOps `discord.client` is well rendered, I don't think it's the error

Comment: @AxelGarcia How about user id in string?

Comment: @GhostOps If the string has a valid id, I even tried calling it as `int(499642019191324692)` but it didn't work anyway

Comment: Have you tried using `bot.get_user` instead? You're using `@bot.command()`, did you define your bot as `bot=command.Bot` or the likes?

Comment: @AxelGarcia can you add your bot definition

Comment: @yotamrec My complete code https://pastebin.com/hbcWHD0x

Comment: @Bagle If I already try to use `bot.get_user` and I have` bot = command.Bot` defined you can see it in my code https://pastebin.com/hbcWHD0x

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thx @Astrogeek for your answer, even if only covering part of the issue. I got a similar issue, and this "bot" instead of client helped me A LOT.

To take the example back :

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = bot.get_user(499642019191324692)
    await user.send('Hello')
```

Should instead be :

```
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = await bot.fetch_user(499642019191324692)
    await user.send('Hello')
```

> await fetch_user(user_id)
> This function is a coroutine.
> Retrieves a User based on their ID. This can only be used by bot accounts. You do not have to share any guilds with the user to get this information, however many operations do require that you do.
> (from DiscordPy API Reference)

Since it's a coroutine, you have to "await" it. If you don't, the coroutine hasn't time to get the user from its ID and it results in a "can't send non-None value to a just-started coroutine" with bot.fetch_user(id)

As said in API you can get user from ID that way, but it only guarantees to deliver the message if bot and user are in a same guild or are friends.

Answer (score 0):

you've used bot.command so it'll be `bot.get_user` instead of `client.get_user`

```py
@bot.command()
async def test(ctx):
    user = bot.get_user(499642019191324692)
    await user.send('Hello')
```

Comment: Unfortunately that method returns an error which is this `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'send'`

Comment: Try using `user.say` instead of `user.send`

Comment: It returns the error `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'say'`